# SQLite inserting multiple rows not working

Tags: java, sqlite, row

I'm trying to insert multiple rows at once using the new syntax introduced in SQLite 3.7.11
I have 3.8.10.2 so this should work fine, but it doesn't.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO leaderheadsplayers (name, uuid, last_join) VALUES ('Pixelados', '79e5ef9b-38dc-41c7-8d12-057f0bf194fb', '2016-08-25 23:21:27'), ('Talismanen_888', '53c0f405-66fa-4852-ad62-215fb6bd63e6', '2016-08-25 23:21:27')
```

When executing this through Java using a PreparedStatement, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)
```

When using a program like DB Browser for SQLite, it works fine.
Executing the same update on MySQL also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Apparently the server wrapper that I'm using has a very outdated version.